# Combine results from multiple mac OS /linux commands in one line

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, command-line

I am using mac OS terminal. I want to print my files information in this format under some directories:

```
md5 content|bytes size|modification date|file name
```

And output this file list need 3 commands : find , stat and md5 (relevant linux command md5sum)

I have tried using this command:

```
find . ! -empty  -type f -exec sh -c "md5 -q '{}' && stat -f '|%z|%SB|%N' '{}'" \;
```

which can output result like this,actually this is near what I want:

> 31408eeb2c34d62638b810e7687d622d
>   
> 269261|Dec 25 15:23:28 2018|./CQIE8846.JPG
>   
> 4f47d55c974f554ec060bd9c2cd54959
>   
> 54150|Jan 18 17:20:08 2019|./Q_try.JPG

but I want each file showed in one line only (2 files found only show 2 lines) :

> 31408eeb2c34d62638b810e7687d622d|269261|Dec 25 15:23:28 2018|./CQIE8846.JPG
>   
> 4f47d55c974f554ec060bd9c2cd54959|54150|Jan 18 17:20:08 2019|./Q_try.JPG

I have tried other  command lines:

case 1)

```
find . ! -empty  -type f -exec stat -f "`md5 -q {}`|%z|%SB|%N" {} \;
```

But the md5 command fail to execute, terminal output like this :

> md5: {}: No such file or directory
>   
> |269261|Dec 25 15:23:28 2018|./CQIE8846.JPG
>   
> |54150|Jan 18 17:20:08 2019|./Q_try.JPG

case 2)

```
find . ! -empty  -type f -exec stat -f '`md5 -q {}`|%z|%B|%N' {} \;
```

fail to interpret md5 commands , output like this

```
`md5 -q ./CQIE8846.JPG`|269261|1545722608|./CQIE8846.JPG
`md5 -q ./Q_try.JPG`|54150|1547803208|./Q_try.JPG
```

Is any way to achieve this with a single command? If not, how do write the expect output with a simple script?

Comment: install gentoo.

Comment: Assign intermediate things to variables and collate the parts with a `printf` at the end... `find ... -exec bash -c 'm=$(md5...); s=$(stat ...); printf "%s|%d|%s..." $m $s'`

Comment: Or write a script called `reportOne` and run `find ... -exec reportOne {} \;`

Comment: Thanks, it works~